# How to deserialize class with public constructor with help of System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, system.text.json

Application written with `C#`, `net7.0`.
Application serializes class and then deserializes it. Serialization works well, but when deserializing a class with a public constructor, the serializer doesn't serialize the property. How to deserialize to object of class with public parameterless constructor?

E.g. i have a class `works`, where `address` = "abc". Object was serialised to `{"address" : "abc"}`. After that it should be deserialized.

Code which used for deserialization:

An object of the following class will be deserialized with `address` = `"abc"`:

```
public class Works
{
    public string address { get; private set; }

    
    Works()
    {
        address = "default";
    }
    public Works(string address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

An object of the following class will be deserialized with `address` = `"default"`, if i remove field initialization it will be deserialized as address = null. How to deserialize it with "abc":

```
public class Doesnt
{
    public string address { get; private set; }

    [JsonConstructor] 
    public Doesnt()
    {
        address = "default";
    }
    public Doesnt(string address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
public byte[] SerializeToBytes<T>(T src)
{
    return JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(src, SerializerOptions);
}
public object Deserialize(byte[] data, Type type)
{
    object res;
    var str =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(str, type, SerializerOptions);
    return res;
}
var objs = new object[]{new Work("abc"),new Doesnt("abc")};
var bytes = SerializeToBytes(obj[0]);
Deserialize(bytes, obj[0].GetType());// reuturns "abc"

bytes = SerializeToBytes(obj[1]);
Deserialize(bytes, obj[1].GetType()); // reuturns "default"
```

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: The `[JsonConstructor]` attribute tells the deserialiser which constructor to use, and you’ve put it on the parameterless constructor?

Comment: @bashis if serialize {address:"abc"}  i expect to get {address:"abc"} after deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Class in example above is immutable. Text.Json.Serializer doesn't deserialize such classes by default, dut there are some ways to do it:

- Parameterized constructors
- Non-public members and property accessors
- Read-only properties (starting from`.net 8` )

Looks like using `[JsonInclude]` or `[JsonConstructor]` with parametrized constructor can be a solution.

```
public class Doesnt
{
    [JsonInclude]  // this can be solution 1
    public string address { get; private set; }

    public Doesnt()
    {
        address = "default";
    }
    [JsonConstructor] //This can be solution 2, parameters should correspond property names
    public Doesnt(string address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Some explanations:

- By default, System.Text.Json uses the default public parameterless constructor
- Parameterized constructor, makes it possible to deserialize an immutable class or struct
- For a struct or a class with multiple constructors, specify the one to use by applying the [JsonConstructor] attribute. When the attribute is not used, a public parameterless constructor is always used if present.
- The parameter names of a parameterized constructor must match the property names and types
- Constructor parameter must match the actual property name even if you use [JsonPropertyName] to rename a property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/immutability#parameterized-constructors